# ASP.Net Core WSFederationAuth Login with Cookie - Site can't be reached

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, claims-based-identity, ws-federation

I'm upgrading an old site to ASP.NET Core 2.1, but still targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2 as the target framework.

We are trying to use WSFederation services to handle authentication as described in this Microsoft [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#use-ws-federation-without-aspnet-core-identity). A separate site handles the actual log-in and then redirects back to our site at the /Federation end-point.

Our Startup.cs class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(authOptions =>
    {
        authOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        authOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        authOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddWsFederation(wsOptions =>
    {
        wsOptions.Wtrealm = Configuration.GetValue<string>("WSFed:Realm");
        wsOptions.MetadataAddress = Configuration.GetValue<string>("WSFed:Metadata");
        wsOptions.CallbackPath = "/Federation";
    })
    .AddCookie(cookieOptions => 
    {
        cookieOptions.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    //Fixes correlation error
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.HttpsPort = 443;
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

We then added the "[Authorize]" attribute to our Home controller. When I run this, I get a "This site can't be reached" error. The webpage at https://localhost:44339/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

When I view the network tab in Chrome dev tools, I can see the cookies being passed around I can see the correct claim information getting passed along, so it looks like that part of it is working correctly.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

**Update**

I added the event wsOptions.Events.OnSecurityTokenValidated and put a breakpoint in. I can see the claims values, so it looks like the authentication took place and that was successful, but I still get the ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR error. If I remove the [Authorize] attribute from the controller, the site runs, but I obviously don't want to remove that attribute.

**Update 2**

It seems that the issue is that the Cookie size is too large. Currently investigating ways to resolve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue appeared to be the cookie/claim size (having too many roles/AD groups).

The ideal solution it seems would be to shrink the size of the cookie/claims, but this isn't realistic for us to do right now.

I got around this by adding an OnSecurityTokenValidated event and within that concatenating the roles into one claim string value with a hard-coded separator between each one. This makes it so you have one claim value for Roles rather than a claim value per role, greatly reducing the size.

```
.AddWsFederation(wsOptions =>
{
    ...
    wsOptions.Events.OnSecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
    {
        //Condense claim data (roles) - otherwise we get errors for too large of claims
        HashSet<Claim> filteredClaims = new HashSet<Claim>();
        HashSet<string> groupSet = new HashSet<string>();
        
        foreach(Claim claim in context.Principal.Claims)
        {
            if(claim.Type != ClaimTypes.Role)
            {
                filteredClaims.Add(claim);
            }
            else
            {
                groupSet.Add(claim.Value);
            }
        }
        filteredClaims.Add(new Claim("<insert new claim key here>", string.Join("zzzsep", groupSet)));

        List <ClaimsIdentity> filteredClaimsIdentity = new List<ClaimsIdentity>() { new ClaimsIdentity(filteredClaims, context.Principal.Identity.AuthenticationType) };
        ClaimsPrincipal newClaimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(filteredClaimsIdentity);
        context.Principal = newClaimsPrincipal;

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    };
})
```

Then when actually getting the groups/roles from the claim, I split the string by the hard-coded separator to get an array of values.

Comment: How was it not realistic for you to do ? Recuding the chunk sizes/overall size of the wsfed cookies has been in challenge in .Net Core. Our apps in .Net Framework don;t have the issue, the chunk size is half the size. Must be the serialization that is different. Any ideas or did you end up reducing the size ?

Comment: The recommendation from Microsoft is to pass minimal authentication data in via the claim, and to get any other data via database queries or something similar. The team that manages claim data at our organization passes in way more data than necessary via the claim, and moving that data into a database takes a lot of time, effort, and cross-team coordination. The solution I posted above was how we "reduced the size" in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

The following is for the .NET Framework; the concepts should apply to Core as well:

Regarding the large cookie used by WSFed, we ran into this issue and found it very difficult to find a clear answer that also provided a good example. The solution is to use what Microsoft calls "reference mode", which creates a much smaller WSFed cookie.

Quote from documentation for the SessionSecurityToken Class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.sessionsecuritytoken?view=netframework-4.8.1:

"A session token can operate in either reference mode or not. If the session token is not operating in reference mode, the entire token is serialized into the session cookie that is stored on the client. The serialized session token can be quite large and thus the cookie stored on the client can also be quite sizeable. In reference mode, rather than serializing the entire session token into the cookie, the token is stored in a session security token cache and only the information used to generate the key necessary to retrieve the token from the cache is stored in the cookie. This can greatly reduce the size of the cookie. The session token cache is implemented by a class derived from SessionSecurityTokenCache and the cache key is implemented by the SessionSecurityTokenCacheKey class. The ContextId and KeyGeneration properties are used in the SessionSecurityTokenCacheKey class to generate the cache key."

This can be accomplished as follows:

1. Create a cache class derived from the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenCache abstract class or use the built-in System.IdentityModel.Configuration.IdentityModelCaches.SessionSecurityTokenCache class and configure it within the caches element of the system.identityModel.identityConfiguration element as follows:

If your cache class was named YourAssembly.YourSessionSecurityTokenCache in YourAssembly.dll:

```
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <caches>
        <sessionSecurityTokenCache type="YourAssembly.YourSessionSecurityTokenCache, YourAssembly" />
      </caches>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
```

Note: Keep in mind that when using the built-in SessionSecurityTokenCache cache that all of the session token information will be stored in-memory, which could get very large with a lot of users. Also, in a web farm scenario if one site goes down then the session token information will be lost and the user will have to login again. This can be mitigated by creating an alternative or exclusive cache in a database or other resilient storage location. In our case I created a custom class that utilized both the in-memory cache for speed and that was backed by a database cache for resiliency in a web farm. Note: There's an example of a SessionSecurityTokenCache implementation on Microsoft's site somewhere that uses a Windows service; however, we found it to be very problematic in regard to performance when having 18 web servers (I'm unable to relocate the article now).

2. Set the IsReferenceMode property to true in the SessionSecurityTokenCreated event. You can do this by modifying Global.asax.cs (recommended by Microsoft) or via a HttpModule (worked great for us), etc.:

Example when using a HttpModule for authentication:

```
var fedAuthModule = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule; 
fedAuthModule.SessionSecurityTokenCreated += FedAuthModule_SessionSecurityTokenCreated; 

private static void FedAuthModule_SessionSecurityTokenCreated(object sender, SessionSecurityTokenCreatedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    //e.SessionToken 
    //e.WriteSessionCookie 

    e.SessionToken.IsReferenceMode = true; 
}
```

3. You should note that the WSFed cookie is much smaller than before after making the web.config and SessionSecurityTokenCache changes.

References:

SessionSecurityTokenCache Class
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.sessionsecuritytokencache?view=netframework-4.8.1

WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SessionSecurityTokenCreated Event
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.services.wsfederationauthenticationmodule.sessionsecuritytokencreated?view=netframework-4.8.1

SessionAuthenticationModule.IsReferenceMode Property
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.services.sessionauthenticationmodule.isreferencemode?view=netframework-4.8.1

Example database schema for a persistent cache (SQL Server):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[YourSessionTokenCache](
    [CONTEXTID] [nchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [ENDPOINTID] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [KEYGENERATION] [nchar](32) NULL,
    [SESSIONSECURITYTOKEN] [image] NOT NULL,
    [EXPIRYTIME] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SESSIONSECTOKENCACHE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CONTEXTID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Note: In our case I added the following columns to this table: CreateDate, CreateUser, ModifyDate, ModifyUser, and UserId (used to identify the user associated with the security token).

Example custom SessionSecurityTokenCache class (without a persistent cache):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Configuration;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Xml;

namespace YourAssembly
{
    public class YourSessionSecurityTokenCache: SessionSecurityTokenCache
    {
        private static readonly IdentityModelCaches Caches = new IdentityModelCaches();
        private static readonly SessionSecurityTokenCache MemoryCache = Caches.SessionSecurityTokenCache;

        public override void AddOrUpdate(SessionSecurityTokenCacheKey key, SessionSecurityToken value, DateTime expiryTime)
        {
            MemoryCache.AddOrUpdate(key, value, expiryTime);
        }

        public override IEnumerable<SessionSecurityToken> GetAll(string endpointId, UniqueId contextId)
        {
            return MemoryCache.GetAll(endpointId, contextId);
        }

        public override SessionSecurityToken Get(SessionSecurityTokenCacheKey key)
        {
            return MemoryCache.Get(key);
        }

        public override void RemoveAll(string endpointId, UniqueId contextId)
        {
            MemoryCache.RemoveAll(endpointId, contextId);
        }

        public override void RemoveAll(string endpointId)
        {
            MemoryCache.RemoveAll(endpointId);
        }

        public override void Remove(SessionSecurityTokenCacheKey key)
        {
            MemoryCache.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Further recommendations:

1. Create performance counters to monitor the cache activity.
2. Allow the in-memory cache to be disabled via configuration when offering a persistent cache as well.